# PhotosPicker inside ForEach get called multiple times onChange

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm building an app to let user create section and upload photos to each section. I have PhotosPicker() inside ForEach sections array

```
ForEach(sections,id: \.self){ section in
     PhotosPicker(
          selection: $selectedItem,
          matching: .images,
          photoLibrary: .shared()) {
              ... 
          }
          .onChange(of: selectedItem) { newItem in
                //This get called multiple times (for each section) even tap on one
          }
}
```

So the idea is that the user can upload a photo to each section inside the for each. But when I do it like this, it triggers the photo picker for each section and ends up uploading the same photo to the same section.

Is there any way to make make the PhotosPicker call once?

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: If you make the PhotosPicker being called once, the user will not be able to add a photo for each section. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: Hi @AlexandreFenyo , what I meant was that I want it to get called once if the user picks the photo one time. Right now with the code above, the onChange is called x amount of time (number of sections) when the user picks one image and it ends up adding the same photo for each section with one action.

Comment: Put the onChange outside the loop you are creating one onChange from each element

Comment: @loremipsum maybe I wasn't clear enough. I have updated the question to reflect it better. So basically for each section, I want to have a button where you can add a photo to it.

Comment: Ah Then you need to put your row in a subview so each can have their own Picker and selected item variable

Comment: Not sure what you meant, do you mean I need to use list view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `section` needs its own `selectedItem` so you have to put the `PhotosPicker` in a subview.

```
import PhotosUI
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct ReusablePhotoPickerView: View{
    //Each row in the ForEach needs its own `@State` right now you are sharing one variable for all the sections.
    @State private var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem?
    //Pass the UIImage to the section
    let onSelected: (Result<UIImage, Error>) -> Void
    var body: some View{
        PhotosPicker(
              selection: $selectedItem,
              matching: .images,
              photoLibrary: .shared()) {
                  Image(systemName: "plus.app")
              }.task(id: selectedItem, {
                  do{
                      let result = try await selectedItem?.getImage()
                      switch result {
                      case .success(let success):
                          onSelected(.success(success))
                      case .failure(let failure):
                          onSelected(.failure(failure))
                      case .none:
                          onSelected(.failure(AppError.noImageFound))
                      }
                  }catch{
                      onSelected(.failure(error))
                  }
              })

    }
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
extension PhotosPickerItem{
    func getImage() async throws -> Result<UIImage, Error>{
        let data = try await self.loadTransferable(type: Data.self)
        guard let data = data, let image = UIImage(data: data) else{
            return .failure(AppError.noImageFound)
        }
        return .success(image)
    }
    
}

enum AppError: LocalizedError{
    case noImageFound
}
```

Once you have decoupled the section process you can assign the `UIImage` to the specific section.

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct MultiPhotoPicker: View {
    @State var sections: [ImageModel] = [.init(description: "flowers"), .init(description: "trees")]
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach($sections) { $section in
                Text(section.description)
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    ForEach($section.images, id:\.cgImage) { $image in
                        Image(uiImage: image)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(height: 40)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    ReusablePhotoPickerView { result in
                        switch result {
                        case .success(let success):
                            //Adding the image to the section.images array
                            $section.wrappedValue.images.append(success)
                        case .failure(let failure):
                            //You should always show errors to the user.
                            print("Error while adding images to \(section.description) \n\(failure)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ImageModel: Identifiable{
        let id: UUID = .init()
        var images: [UIImage] = []
        var description: String
    }
}
```